# Selective Sort in Java

Tags: java

I have to make a list of pilots with their number of flying hours and make a slective sort ascending and descending.
I made the ascending selective sort of hours but i don't know how to make the program to show the ascending order of names based on hours.

This is what I did.
Can you help me?

```
int arr[]={50,150,100,250,200,24,376,541,56,164};
int arrLength = arr.length;
for(int i=0;i<arrLength-1;i++){
    int min=i;
    for (int k=i+1;k<arrLength;k++){
        if(arr[k]<arr[min]){
            min = k;
        }
    }
    if (i != min) {
        int temp=arr[i];
        arr[i]=arr[min];
        arr[min]=temp;
    }
}
for (int j=0;j<arrLength;j++) {
    System.out.println(arr[j]+" ");}
}
```

}

Comment: Where are the pilots?

Answer (score 1):

You use a swap functionality. When you do this, you are swapping the hour values between indices. It is then, then you should also swap corresponding pilot's names. That way for every swap, the pilots will also be swapped.

The swap function I am talking about is this:

```
int temp=arr[i];
arr[i]=arr[min];
arr[min]=temp;
```

Do something like:

```
String tempName = names[i];
names[i] = names[min];
names[min] = tempName;
```

---

Another thing to consider would be creating a `Pilot` class. In doing so, you would maintain an OOP concept and could more-easily handle sorting.

For example,

```
public class Pilot implements Comparable<Pilot> {

    int hours;
    String name;

    public Pilot(String name, int hours){
        this.name = name;
        this.hours = hours;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Pilot other){
        return hours.compareTo(other.hours);
    }

}
```

You could then use the `Pilot#compareTo(Pilot)` function to figure out how to sort the pilots based off the numbers of hours or even completely change the way you want to sort them from there.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `TreeMap` to store the Pilot with their flying hours, then Java automatically sorts it for you based on the value (make that the hours).

**Set Up A `HashTree`**

```
public static Map<String, Integer> pilots = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();
```

**Then to add values to it:**

pilots.put(pilot, pilotHours);

**In your case, you could use some code looking like this (from the given code):**

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

   public class Test {

public static Map<String, Integer> pilots = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int arr[] = { 50, 150, 100, 250, 200, 24, 376, 541, 56, 164 };
    int arrLength = arr.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < arrLength - 1; i++) {
        int min = i;
        for (int k = i + 1; k < arrLength; k++) {
            if (arr[k] < arr[min]) {
                min = k;
            }
        }
        if (i != min) {
            int temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[min];
            arr[min] = temp;
        }
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < arrLength; j++) {
        System.out.println(arr[j] + " ");
    }

    for (int p = 0; p < arrLength; p++) {

        int pilotHours = arr[p];
        String pilot = "PILOT NAME, HOWEVER YOU GET IT";

        pilots.put(pilot, pilotHours);

    }
    System.out.println(pilots);
}
   }
```

Tell me how it goes, after adjusting it to fit your code.

The main answer/suggestion would be to use a `TreeMap`

Comment: @Obicere, My bad, I meant a TreeMap

Comment: If I compile your code,it still sorts me the numbers.Where I put pilots names? Sorry for being such a n00b but it's my first homework in java after few classes so..

Comment: @user3163682, If I'm understanding you correctly, in my code where it says, `String pilot = "PILOT NAME, HOWEVER YOU GET IT";` that is the Pilot name as a simple string, but if you have an array with the pilot names, then you can simply put the  `String pilot = "PILOT NAME, HOWEVER YOU GET IT";` into the for loop and set pilot = to `pilotArray[p]`  then it should work.

Comment: I built another file with an ArrayList with pilot names but I still cannot link them

Comment: If it is an `ArrayList`, then use:     String pilot = pilotArrayList.get(p).toString();

Comment: I think I will give up soon.

Comment: Giving up is never the right way to go! Once you get it to work, the feeling alone is enough of a reward to keep going!

Comment: The more I change things in my project,the more I realise I have no idea what I'm doing and no target at all :))

Comment: Try making a copy of your code to experiment with, and keep one original version.

Comment: I don't even think I made the right ArrayList..Can you help me with this ?

Answer (score 1):

Pair together the names of the pilots with the corresponding number of hours. Sort this array of (name, hours) pairs using only the number of hours as sorting criterion for your selection sort. Then traverse the sorted array of pairs and display only the names of the pilots, they will be in the expected order.

A related solution would be to use (index, hours) pairs where index refers to your original array of pilot names. When traversing the sorted array of pairs, the matching pilot name can be referenced in the original array by using this index. This approach avoids duplicating the array of pilot names in the array of pairs in case you have constraints on the input or memory use.

An implementation of the second solution would look like this (preserving most of your original code):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> nameArr=new ArrayList<String>();
        nameArr.add("John");
        nameArr.add("Robert");
        nameArr.add("Duncan");
        nameArr.add("Steve");
        nameArr.add("Adrian");
        nameArr.add("Paul");
        nameArr.add("Michael");
        nameArr.add("Andrew");
        nameArr.add("Henry");
        nameArr.add("Bradley");
        int arr[]={50,150,100,250,200,24,376,541,56,164};
        int arrLength = arr.length;
        assert arrLength == nameArr.size();

        int indexArr[]=new int[arrLength];
        for(int i=0;i<arrLength;i++){
            indexArr[i]=i;
        }

        for(int i=0;i<arrLength-1;i++){
            int min=i;
            for (int k=i+1;k<arrLength;k++){
                if(arr[k]<arr[min]){
                    min = k;
                }
            }
            if (i != min) {
                int temp=arr[i];
                arr[i]=arr[min];
                arr[min]=temp;

                temp=indexArr[i];
                indexArr[i]=indexArr[min];
                indexArr[min]=temp;
            }
        }

        for (int j=0;j<arrLength;j++) {
            int index=indexArr[j];
            String name=nameArr.get(index);
            System.out.println(name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand what you say but I have no idea how to do it. I am new in Java,started few weeks ago. Can you build this code for me ?

Comment: @user3163682 I edited the answer to add a sample implementation of the second solution.